# Not able to connect to mysql-router on IPv6 address

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, ipv6, mysqlrouter

I am deploying mysqlrouter with IPv6 address on kubernetes cluster, router is deploying and is able to connect to mysql instances, but the router itself is not being able to connect to application services. Also I tried to do telnet to the mysqlrouter it say's can't connect to remote host, connection refuse.

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql/mysql-router:latest

COPY mysqlrouter.conf /etc/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.conf
```

mysqlrouter.conf file

```
[Default]
bind_address = ::
```

Please help out here if anyone earlier faces similar issue.